# make object instance immutable

Tags: perl, immutability, moose

I want to be able to instantiate a Moose based object add to it until I serialize it and then I want to make it unchangeable. How can/should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would make two classes and a common Role:

```
package Thing
use Moose::Role;

has some_attrib => (isa => 'AnotherThing');

### Behaviour (the important stuff) goes here

package ImmutableThing;
use Moose;

with 'Thing';

has +some_attrib => (is => 'ro');

sub finalize { shift }

package MutableThing
use Moose;

with 'Thing';

has +some_attrib => (is => 'rw');

sub finalize {
    my $self = shift;
    Thing->new({some_attrib => $self->some_attrib});
}
```

I'm not sure that having mutable and immutable forms of the same class is necessarily a good idea though. I tend to try and think about build time and operation time as two distinct phases with different interfaces.

I would be more inclined to write a Parameter Collector (I've capitalised it like it's a pattern, but I've not seen it in the literature) that has an interface optimised to gathering the info needed to create a Thing, and the Thing Itself, which is the object that's *used* by the rest of the program.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is Factory which knows how to construct an object

Comment: Well, yes, sort of. But I'm expecting the parameters required to be collected over multiple method calls. But that could just be me misunderstanding what a Factory is.

Comment: no, I guess not, actually Effective Java has a build pattern kind of like that because it doesn't support hashes for constructors. On the other hand I'm starting to wonder if this doesn't all come down to not treating undef as unset in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of (and can't easily find) any modules to do this on CPAN which is surprising but explains why you are asking :-)

A "before" modifier over all your attributes is the obvious way to go about it. I'm sure there's a suitable meta-programming way to get a list of all attribute accessors and apply the modifier, but I'd be tempted to explicitly list them all with a big comment.

Have you considered whether you have one class or two here (Thingy, LockedThingy)? Two classes would let you encapsulate the meta cleverness if you're that way inclined.

Comment: I've considered numerous things... in all honesty I can probably figure out how to do it via the mop, but I kind of asked to see what all the idea's on how to do it are.